# Cannot solve a type mismatching with GADT

Tags: ocaml, gadt

I have following type definition of `x` with a GADT.

```
type x = X : 'a option -> x
```

and I'm trying to write a function to get the value of `option` accompanying with tag `X`

I first tried the following

```
let get = fun (X a)->a
```

and obtained the following error message

```
Error: This expression has type $X_'a option
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type constructor $X_'a would escape its scope
```

secondly I tried this

```
let get : type a.x-> a option =  fun (X a)->a
```

and following

```
Error: This expression has type $X_'a option
       but an expression was expected of type a option
       Type $X_'a is not compatible with type a
```

I think since the type `'a` given to the `option` inside type `x` doesn't appear in type annotation, there is no way to write what `'a` actually is in type annotation explicitly.

Comment: This is succeed.`module M = struct type t type x = X : t option -> x end
let get : M.x -> M.t option = fun (M.X a)->a`

Answer (score 2):

You're exactly right. You *can't* access that type. It's an *existential* type, which means it can't be recovered. There's no magic trick to reconstruct such a type from a runtime value, as that would require the compiler to know about the runtime value of an expression at compile-time.

Perhaps you meant to include the type `'a` as part of the type of `x`?

```
type 'a x = X : 'a option -> 'a x
```

which doesn't require the GADT syntax anymore and can be written more succinctly as

```
type 'a x = X of 'a option
```

Comment: thank you for quick answer. but the code I gave above is simplified version I'm fighting with now which is more larger gadt definiton and more complicated.

Comment: thank you. your explanation vely helps me. I will use ordinary variant. The code using a module did pass some of code but since they aren't polymorphic, finally fails somewhere. Thank you your answer!!

Comment: I got it. What I was trying to do was to get the type that is hidden by an existential type, which is impossible.

Comment: Exactly! If you need access to the type, you have to keep track of it somewhere. Existentials eliminate that information, and there's no way to recover it once it's gone.